# PostgreSQL earthdistance Installation Mac

Tags: postgresql, earthdistance

The installation of `earthdistance module` in `Postgresql 9.6.5` on `OSX El Capitan 10.11.6`.  PG is already installed, working.  I created the `extension`, which installs `cube` first:

```
rich=# CREATE EXTENSION earthdistance CASCADE;
NOTICE:  installing required extension "cube"
CREATE EXTENSION
```

Restarted my box.  Opened up `psql`, chose the proper database, asked about functions (`\df`):

```
    rich=# \df
                                                                                     List of functions
     Schema |        Name        | Result data type |           Argument data types            |  Type
    --------+--------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------+--------
     public | cube               | cube             | cube, double precision                   | normal
     public | cube               | cube             | cube, double precision, double precision | normal
     public | cube               | cube             | double precision                         | normal
     public | cube               | cube             | double precision, double precision       | normal
     public | cube               | cube             | double precision[]                       | normal
     public | cube               | cube             | double precision[], double precision[]   | normal
     public | cube_cmp           | integer          | cube, cube                               | normal
     public | cube_contained     | boolean          | cube, cube                               | normal
     public | cube_contains      | boolean          | cube, cube                               | normal
     public | cube_coord         | double precision | cube, integer                            | normal
     public | cube_coord_llur    | double precision | cube, integer                            | normal
     public | cube_dim           | integer          | cube                                     | normal
     public | cube_distance      | double precision | cube, cube                               | normal
     public | cube_enlarge       | cube             | cube, double precision, integer          | normal
     public | cube_eq            | boolean          | cube, cube                               | normal
     public | cube_ge            | boolean          | cube, cube                               | normal
     public | cube_gt            | boolean          | cube, cube                               | normal
     public | cube_in            | cube             | cstring                                  | normal
     public | cube_inter         | cube             | cube, cube                               | normal
     public | cube_is_point      | boolean          | cube                                     | normal
     public | cube_le            | boolean          | cube, cube                               | normal
     public | cube_ll_coord      | double precision | cube, integer                            | normal
     public | cube_lt            | boolean          | cube, cube                               | normal
     public | cube_ne            | boolean          | cube, cube                               | normal
     public | cube_out           | cstring          | cube                                     | normal
     public | cube_overlap       | boolean          | cube, cube                               | normal
     public | cube_size          | double precision | cube                                     | normal
     public | cube_subset        | cube             | cube, integer[]                          | normal
     public | cube_union         | cube             | cube, cube                               | normal
     public | cube_ur_coord      | double precision | cube, integer                            | normal
     public | distance_chebyshev | double precision | cube, cube                               | normal
     public | distance_taxicab   | double precision | cube, cube                               | normal
     public | earth              | double precision |                                          | normal
     public | earth_box          | cube             | earth, double precision                  | normal
     public | earth_distance     | double precision | earth, earth                             | normal
     public | g_cube_compress    | internal         | internal                                 | normal
     public | g_cube_consistent  | boolean          | internal, cube, smallint, oid, internal  | normal
     public | g_cube_decompress  | internal         | internal                                 | normal
     public | g_cube_distance    | double precision | internal, cube, smallint, oid, internal  | normal
     public | g_cube_penalty     | internal         | internal, internal, internal             | normal
     public | g_cube_picksplit   | internal         | internal, internal                       | normal
     public | g_cube_same        | internal         | cube, cube, internal                     | normal
     public | g_cube_union       | cube             | internal, internal                       | normal
     public | gc_to_sec          | double precision | double precision                         | normal
     public | geo_distance       | double precision | point, point                             | normal
     public | latitude           | double precision | earth                                    | normal
     public | ll_to_earth        | earth            | double precision, double precision       | normal
     public | longitude          | double precision | earth                                    | normal
     public | sec_to_gc          | double precision | double precision                         | normal
    (49 rows)
```

So it seems the `extension` is loaded fine.  As a test, I'm using the following simple command:

```
SELECT point(43.664828,-79.341620) <@> point(44.418390, -80.096013)
```

In `psql` I am not receiving any feedback.  In `Postico 1.3.2` (a PG client), I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: point <@> point
LINE 1: SELECT point(43.664828,-79.341620) <@> point(44.418390, -80....
                                           ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

It seems the module is not installed, as per the feedback.  I am expecting this to work, as the `extension` is installed properly, and I am using the proper syntax for the `earth_distance` `function`.  I have tried other queries with the same type of error, indicating non-recognition of operators.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.  Turns out you have to choose the `database` for the `extension` to apply to that specific `database`.  Just entering `psql` is inside the application level, so the `CREATE EXTENSION earthdistance CASCADE` is still blind to any database apparently.  So enter `psql` using the `psql <dbname>` syntax and then apply the `CREATE EXTENSION earthdistance CASCADE` for it to apply to your chosen database.